# Orbeon : Show in Email Subject settings

Tags: orbeon

I have checked **Show in Email Subject** checkbox from settings, to add that value in Email Subject.

I want to contact this with other control's value too.
so I did the same , check Show in Email Subject checkbox.

but now in email subject it is concatenating these value with ","

ex:

control 1 : projectNum

control 2: projectName

control 3: city

Email subject should be:  **projectNum - projectName - city**

But it is displaying comma separated values. how to change it with other separator like "-" or ":"?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a coma used as a separator because [the relevant code in `email-form.xpl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-4.3.1.0-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/email/email-form.xpl#L214) does a `string-join(…, ', ')`. If you want another separator to be used, you can either:

- Change `email-form.xpl` to always use that other separator.
- In your form, create another field, which is:

  1. calculated as a `string-join()` of the fields you want to show in the title using the separator you want;
  2. not visible to users, e.g. visibility set to `false()`;
  3. the only field marked as showing in the email subject.